# Prints the ASM code to generate the given class

Tags: java, eclipse, java-bytecode-asm

I am having problems with a Java program when running it on eclipse.

Message:

```
Prints the ASM code to generate the given class.
Usage: ASMifier [-debug] <fully qualified class name or class file name>
```

Does someone know this message? and what needs to be done?

Comment: Maybe it's a command line tool and you need to pass it a java file to decompile?

Comment: I checked that. I have the code on a JAVA file.

Comment: I found something else. "import org.objectweb.asm.*" is in my code. I have no idea how this happened. I deleted it and now the Aplication is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete "import org.objectweb.asm.*" from your code if this is not needed.